# Updating another kendo grid once current grid updated

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two kendo grid in one page and the results of the first grid should be reflected to the second grid. For instance, **Grid1** = ***list of subjects***, **Grid2** = ***list of students***, if I have to add new subject, it should be right away available on the students dropdown column for subjects without the need of refreshing the whole page.

Hopefully someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: So you don't want to update a second grid, but a dropdown instead. How its your dropdown(it is a kendo dropdown) and how/when your primary grid is update? Providing some code snippets would be nice to help us.

Comment: You can updated the dropdown datasource with a ajax call to server. Would like to see your code to express more in detail. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by having an ajax call inside `complete: function(e){ // ajax call to update  }` to update the dropdownlist. Thank you guys.